# Using Regex to validate a variable length string

Tags: java, android, regex

I'm trying to validate a form field in Java using Regex, which can have 5 different format possibilities. I'm struggling to get this one working.

The string to be checked will be between 4-6 alphanumeric characters.

If it's 4 characters, it must be all numbers.

```
^\\d{4}$
```

If it's 5 characters, it can be all numbers, first position letter with 4 following numbers, or first 3 positions letters followed with 2 numbers.

```
 ^\\d{5}$
 ^[a-zA-Z]\\d{4}$
 ^[a-zA-Z]{3}\\d{2}$
```

And if it's 6 characters, it will be first position letter, 4 numbers, and last another letter.

```
^[a-zA-Z]\\d{4}[a-zA-Z]$
```

I just can't seem to piece it all together though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is just list each acceptable pattern in a group, separated by alternations (`|`):

```
^(\\d{4}|\\d{5}|[a-zA-Z]\\d{4}|[a-zA-Z]{3}\\d{2}|[a-zA-Z]\\d{4}[a-zA-Z])$
```

But you can improve this a little bit by combining some of the alternatives:

```
^([a-zA-Z\\d]?\\d{4}|[a-zA-Z]{3}\\d{2}|[a-zA-Z]\\d{4}[a-zA-Z])$
```

Comment: That works... thank you! I didn't realize I could use the or operator in the regex string directly...I was putting it in the if statement.